# Automatic compiling between languages

Tags: c++, python

**EDIT: Solved, thanks everyone!**

What I would like to be able to do in simple terms is take user input from one programming language, convert it into another programming language and have it compiled automatically.

For example (simplified and not precisely what I want to do but along similar lines):

1) Write a python script, userData = raw_input("blah blah blah, example, example")

2) if userData == "blah blah blah, example, example", serialize to a text file called "example.cpp" and put in some predetermined data which is based on the user's input (written in C++ form, though represented as a string in python script). For simplification this predetermined data will be called predeterminedData.

3) The extent of predeterminedData will be essentially a cout << "this is a different message to before" << endl;

4) The compiler (g++/gcc) compiles this automatically and the overall program structure calls the newly created executable file.

If someone could help point me toward the topic/topics I should read up on to be able to achieve this - if it's possible - that'd be fantastic.

**Edit:** I've made a classic mistake I think. In an attempt to not be accused of asking other people to do my "homework" for me I've been too vague and consequently misleading. Thank you for the responses so far but perhaps now I should be more specific. It isn't particularly python nor c++ specific but I will explain beneath. I apologize for not being more explicit before.

What I actually want to achieve is quite simple. I want to use user input from one programming language (python, c++, java) and have it create a Lilypond script which will automatically compile and create a midi file.

So for example:

1) User is asked to enter alphabetically a series of notes: e.g. "C" then "E" then "F", so on and so on.

2) These "notes" are checked by a control loop statement and a string is created in the Lilypond script and serialized to a file which is compatible with its compiler (example.ly)

3) This file is automatically compiled by the Lilypond compiler and creates a midi file (example.midi)

4) Later in the program this example.midi can be called on and played back because of this creation process. It would not have existed prior to this creation.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you want, but why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you're just looking for a template processor, which takes C++ source code and replaces certain magic sequences "substitution variables" with a string from the python program?  The C++ compiler can do this all by itself, see the `-D` compiler option to define a macro from the command line.

Comment: How deep is your enthusiasm well?

Comment: Unless I miss something, you're asking for the C++ compiler to be run during execution, and there's no standard way to do that.  (It may or may not be possible to do it with ugly hacks on a given system.)  Alternately, you may be looking for something like C++ templates, although those are a lot harder to work with than Python.

Comment: So you essentially need to have a preprocessor.  Could be as simple as using your own build script where your script gets run, then immediately after your other compiler gets runs.

Comment: Stupid question alert: Is reading about using preprocessors as simple as a quick google search or a flip through a book? Is there a source you could recommend?

Comment: That's entirely dependent on your platform, what kind of program you're working with or willing to work with.  This is akin to a data build in game development.  But you can use a bash script or a batch file for linux or windows, or even attempt to use a language that easily installs to either OS as your build script, like python for example.

Comment: It would most likely be python I would use.

Comment: A quick look at the Lilypond page suggests that Lilypond is to make beautiful sheet music and not any sort of sound file.  That being said, Python does have facilities for calling other programs, so there's no reason you couldn't call a .midi compiler.

Comment: Well Lilypond can make midi files but this intrigues me: "That being said, Python does have facilities for calling other programs, so there's no reason you couldn't call a .midi compiler."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me it sounds like you just want to write a user interface for interactive creation of `lilypond` files.

I don't see what all this has to do with compilation. Your python script will need to write a file in lilypond notation and afterwards your script needs to call `lilypond` on that file (e.g. with `os.system`). You could even skip writing to a file and just pipe the output to `stdin` which `lilypond` can also read.

Comment: Now that you phrase it like that, it is exactly what I am attempting to do. How could I go about learning how to "call lilypond" with the os.system or using stdin? Any clue as to where I could read up on it?

Comment: Apologies, read up on it. Now working like a charm. Thank you so much pmr and everyone else for their input.

Comment: @JayCarter Nice. Please remember to accept answers and you might want to read the FAQ to get to know StackOverflow better. You will probably come back with more questions.